# python can't import its own packages from the project root

Tags: python, flask, python-import, python-poetry

Here is the structure of the python project:

```
├── app
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── api
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   └── endpoints
│   │       ├── __init__.py
│   │       ├── about.py
│   │       ├── auth.py
│   │       ├── main_p.py
│   │       ├── trucks.py
│   │       └── users.py
│   ├── main.py
│   ├── static
│   └── templates
├── poetry.lock
└── pyproject.toml
```

I can't import from the project root.

If I do the import in this way, everything works:

```
from api.endpoints.auth import authorization as auth_blueprint
```

But I need to do it this way:

```
from app.api.endpoints.auth import authorization as auth_blueprint
```

How can I do it correctly?

Comment: How do you execute the code?

Comment: Why do you need to do `from app.api.api...` if `from api...` works?

Comment: inside the main root , add `main.py` file where you import flask instance, ie app and set `FLASK_ENV =main:app` something like this , this will work

Comment: My main goal is to understand how to do an import from the root folder of the project and what is causing this error

I run the code in terminal: 
python3 app/main.py

Comment: ... is this project installed? what's in the pyproject.toml?

Comment: `from api... import ...` requires `api` to be a top-level import package, but it is not. The top-level import package is `app`, so all your (absolute) imports need to start with `from app... import ...` (or `import app...`). Of course you could also use relative imports, but it is added complexity (I always recommend to get everything working with absolute imports, and then if necessary slowly convert to relative imports). -- https://sinoroc.github.io/kb/python/python_imports.html